# Godot. Переменная получает 'null' при повторном запуске игры(f6). При первом запуске все работает корректно

Tags: godot, timeout, signal

Читал документацию по godot и повторял оттуда примеры. И возникла сложность на этапе изучения использования сигналов(https://docs.godotengine.org/ru/4.x/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html). Скрипт писал на GDScript. При запуске игры дебагер мне показывает ошибку "invalid get index 'timeout' (on base:'null instance')". Хотя все сделано абсолютно идентично примеру из документации, возникает такая сложность. И что самое странное, когда я захожу в другой проект, потом снова перехожу в этот и включаю игру, все работает, спрайт исчезает каждую секунду. Но когда я не выхожу из проекта и перезапускаю его, вылезает такая ошибка. Подскажите с чем связано? Не хочется идти дальше не разобравшись). Скрин сцен и файлов прилагаю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
extends Sprite2D

var speed = 400
var angular_speed = PI


func _ready():
    var timer = get_node("Timer")
    timer.timeout.connect(_on_timer_timeout)


func _process(delta):
    rotation += angular_speed * delta
    var velocity = Vector2.UP.rotated(rotation) * speed
    position += velocity * delta


func _on_button_pressed():
    set_process(not is_processing())


func _on_timer_timeout():
    visible = not visible
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нода `Sprite2D` создан как отдельная сцена, нода `Timer` находится в `Node2D`, при запуске `Node2D` - код находит `Timer`, но если запустить `Sprite2D` как отдельную сцену код не находит `Timer`.
Есть 2 решения:

1. Переместить `Timer` непосредственно на сцену `Sprite2D`,
2. Не делать из ветки `Sprite2D` отдельную сцену.

[image: Cцена "Sprite2D"]

Comment: спасибо огромное! все было так просто) вы мне очень помогли